# Appending an array inside a struct - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, swift2

I have a struct

```
struct Question {
    let title: [String]
    let additionalInfo: String?
    let answers: [String]
}
```

additionally i have created an array with struct object's values like so

```
var questions = [
   Question(title: ["What is this color", "Looks like orange"], additionalInfo: nil, answers: [
        "Blue",
        "Red"
        ]),
    Question(title: ["Some random question", "some random question detail"], additionalInfo: "additional info", answers: [
        "London",
        "Liverpool"
        ]),
    Question(title: ["Some random question 2", "Some random question detail 2"], additionalInfo: nil, answers: [
        "some answer 1",
        "some answer 2"
        ])
]
```

I've been playing around a little and that's what i came up with

```
var routines = [questions]
self.routines.append(questions(Question(title: "extra value", additionalInfo: nil, answers:nil)))
```

The problem is - it doesn't work.

What is the proper way of inserting a value inside the already existing array wrapped in a struct?

Comment: pl. check the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373400/swift-append-to-array-in-struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
questions.append(Question(title: ["extra value"], additionalInfo: nil, answers:["answer"]))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but you have to wrap the Question inside an array. Another issue is - it creates a new record, but how do i append a value into an already existing record? Let's say "title" array?

Comment: Declare `title` as `var` instead of `let` and you can do this: `questions[2].title.append("something")`.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what that extra `questions` is doing in the append, shouldnt it be

```
self.routines.append(Question(title:["extra value"], additionalInfo: nil, answers:nil))
```